# How to delete an element from custom array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code below

```
Box **b = 0;
//memory allocated for elements of rows.
b = new Box *[ROWS] ;

//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
for( int i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++ )
    b[i] = new Box[COLUMNS];       

b[0][0] = NULL;
```

Why do I get error saying: "no viable overload '='" on last line of code.

Comment: +1 for actually using array `delete[]` there, even if you got much of the rest mixed up :)

Comment: The last line may give you a runtime error, as you write to unallocated memory.

Comment: I haven't yet seen such a messed up piece of code :/

Comment: sorry guys, I edit my code. this should be right

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code. First, why do you allocate `int`, when your type is `Box`? This should be `b = new Box *[ROWS]` or `b[i] = new Box[COLUMNS];` respectively.

Also, you are trying to set a memory location, that you have previously freed with `delete`, which is dangerous and may lead to unforeseen consequences.

This line

```
b[0][0] = NULL;
```

is not possible, since your type at `b[0][0]` is not `Box*` but `Box`

Answer (score 0):

`new int*` will return a `int**`. Compiler is complanining that this `int**` can not be converted to `Box**` (type of `b`).

Answer (score 0):

you declare a jagged array of `Box`, yet assign `new int*[]` - what is going on there?

Also `b[0][0]` would be of type `Box&`. You can't assign `NULL` unless

- `Box::Box` has an implicit constructor taking a parameter of a type to which `NULL` is convertible
- `Box::Box` defines an assignment operator overload taking such a parameter

Answer (score 0):

you havn't overload'=' in the class Box

Answer (score 0):

```
b[0][0] = NULL;
```

That's wrong for two reasons:

- `b[0][0]` refers to an object type `Box` (since `b` is `Box**`, so `b[0]` is `Box*`). You're trying to assign a pointer to it, which is an error (unless `Box` is convertible from a pointer).
- You've just deleted the memory that `b` points to, so dereferencing it is an error anyway.

Just remove that line. Depending on what you're planning to do with `b` afterwards, it might make sense to assign `b = NULL` to avoid a dangling pointer.